# Explanation of parameters from bitcoin/src/chainparams.cpp

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

Please explain the following parameters in bitcoin chainparams.cpp file

> consensus.powLimit =
>   int256S("00000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff");
>          consensus.nPowTargetTimespan = 14 * 24 * 60 * 60; // two weeks
>          consensus.nPowTargetSpacing = 10 * 60;
>          consensus.fPowAllowMinDifficultyBlocks = false;
>          consensus.fPowNoRetargeting = false;